Let $T_{-1}(x)=x^3+x$. Prove that $T_{-1}$ is not structurally stable.

Let $T_{-1}(x)=x^3+x$. Prove that $T_{-1}$ is not structurally stable.

Let $f:J\to J$. $f$ is said to be $C^r$-structurally stable on $J$ if there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that whenever $d_r(f,g)<\epsilon$ for $g:J\to J$, it follows that $f$ is topologically conjugate to $g$.
Let us see if $T$ is $C^1$ structurally stable on $\mathbb{R}$. We need find a $\epsilon>0$ such that if $d_1(T,G)<\epsilon$, then $T$ and $G$ are topologically conjugate.
Proposed solution:
Let $T_{-1}(x)=x^3+x$ and $G_{-1}(x)= (x^3+x)\epsilon$.
Then $T'=3x^2+1$ and $G'=3\epsilon x^2 + \epsilon$.
We calculate the distance $$d_1(T,G)=|3x^2+1-3\epsilon x^2 - \epsilon|=1 - \epsilon + (3 - 3 \epsilon) x^2<\epsilon$$ holds when $\epsilon=1\implies 1<0$.
Then since the definition is satisfied for the value $\epsilon=1$, since it requires $d_r(f,g)<\epsilon$ for $g:J\to J$, we see that $T_{-1}$ IS structurally stable.
So, what is the error here?
Thanks

Thanks, how did you choose that?

Do you always add this linear term to the smallest polynomial?

Thanks, this was not given in Devaney's respective chapter on this problem. So adding a small linear perturbation $\epsilon x$ is always the right method for any type of function.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
